# Suppressing an unwanted new tab in Safari

Tags: safari

My bank has a new "improved" online server.  One of the "wonderful" new features is that clicking **any** link or button opens a new tab to "check my credit score" AND puts that tab in the foreground.

I can use /etc/hosts to change the tab to a 404, but I'd rather not get it at all.

The bank is ignoring my complaints (probably because they're swamped with phone calls about why no one can log in to their new IOS app).

I don't really want to create a proxy just for this.  Is there a way to make Safari discard any links to a particular domain?

Comment: Are all solution methods acceptable? First-party only; macros; extensions?

Comment: I'll consider any, but hopefully simple.  Because it's sim[ple enough to close the tab every time.  Still irritating, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more elegant solutions! But in the absence of those, I would write a macro to monitor and immediately close the tab.

Pseudocode:

- In Safari, whenever the focused window's name changes:

  - (maybe wait a fraction of a second)
  - If the name is [name of credit score page]:

    - Select menu item File > Close Tab.
      (or hit ⌘W, or run an AppleScript)

This may be similarly achievable using other macro programs, but here's how it looks in Keyboard Maestro: (this macro would be placed in a group designated to be active only in Safari, or in all web browsers, to minimize impact)

[image: Keyboard Maestro screenshot]

Comment: The open/switch/close flash would still be irritating, but it would be an improvement on the current situation.  Thanks

Comment: Agreed! I hope someone has a better answer.